# can't resolve path to PIE.htc

Tags: css, internet-explorer, grails, css3pie

I'm trying to integrate css3pie with a Grails app. According to [the instructions](http://css3pie.com/documentation/getting-started/), all I should need to do is:

- place the PIE.htc file somewhere on the server
- add the following to every relevant CSS rule `behavior: url(path/to/PIE.htc);`

In order to simplify figuring out the path to PIE.htc, I placed the file in `web-app/js/PIE.htc`. I then defined the following URL mapping

```
"/PIE.htc"(controller: 'home', action: 'css3pie')
```

which is handled by the action:

```
class HomeController implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private ResourceLoader resourceLoader

    void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.resourceLoader = applicationContext
    }

    def css3pie() {
        log.debug "css3pie HTC file requested"
        Resource pieHTC = resourceLoader.getResource('/js/PIE.htc')
        response.contentType = 'text/x-component'
        response.outputStream << pieHTC.file.text
        response.outputStream.flush()
    }
}
```

If you navigate to http://summer-festivals.cloudfoundry.com/PIE.htc the file is served, so everything appears to be working. I then added the `behavior` property to a few CSS rules, to see if it's working, e.g.

```
.roundBottomLeft {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 10px;
    behavior: url(/PIE.htc);
}

.roundBottomRight {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 10px;
    behavior: url(/PIE.htc);
}
```

This should round the bottom-right and bottom-left corners of the menu, but if you view the [homepage](http://summer-festivals.cloudfoundry.com/) in IE8 you can see it's not working.

I seems there's a problem resolving the path to the `PIE.htc` file, because I set a breakpoint within the `css3pie` action above, but the breakpoint is never hit. Why is the path to `PIE.htc` not being resolved.

Comment: I had problems with PIE.htc not being called before. Try putting it in your root folder. Plus I think the path is always relative to root and not to the actual folder. So `behavior: url(PIE.htc)` will look for it in root even if it's called from within `../css`

Comment: Don -- I've had similar problems with Internet Explorer not getting PIE.htc, even when I try various paths and copy PIE.htc to multiple directories, e.g. webapp and webapp/css. It seems to work in some gsps, and then not in others, even though it is the exact same css element.  Were you able to resolve the path issue for regular style sheet usage?  If so, if you post an answer I'd certainly be grateful.

Comment: @Ray no I gave up on PIE.htc because it seemed to be causing more problems than it was solving

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, PIE only recognizes shorthand styles. So you need to use border-radius with the per-corner shorthand values rather than individual border-x-y-radius properties.

http://css3pie.com/documentation/known-issues/#shorthand

http://css3pie.com/documentation/supported-css3-features/#border-radius

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I've just modified your code a little bit:

**URLMappings.groovy**

```
class UrlMappings {
    static mappings = {
        "/$controller/$action?/$id?"{
            constraints {
                // apply constraints here
            }
        }
        "/"(controller:'home')
        "500"(view:'/error')
        "403"(view:'/login/denied')
        "/static/PIE.htc"(controller: 'home',action: 'css3pie') // <== see here
    }
}
```

**HomeController.groovy**

```
import grails.plugins.springsecurity.Secured
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource

@Secured("IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY")
class HomeController {

    def grailsApplication

    def index = { }

    def css3pie() {
        Resource pieHTC = grailsApplication.mainContext.getResource('css/PIE.htc') // <== see here
        response.contentType = 'text/x-component'
        response.outputStream << pieHTC.file.text
        response.outputStream.flush()
    }
}
```